# How to ssh in the face of huge (30 second) latency?

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, latency

I need to create an ssh connection between two Linux machines running Centos v5 but the latency could be as high as 30 seconds.  I find that if I test something approaching this configuration artificially by simulating 7 seconds or more latency using:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 7s
```

When I try:

```
ssh -n -o ConnectTimeout=0 WilliamKF@centos5Machine whoami
```

It fails after about 1 min 23 sec with:

```
Connection closed by 10.35.50.114
```

Note that ConnectTimeout=0 means never timeout. Also, simulating a latency of 6 seconds results in a successful ssh after about 1 min 32 sec.

Is there anything I can do to get ssh to work in the face of extremely high latency on Linux?  Why does ssh fail at this threshold

Comment: `whoami` is supposed to end after reply.

Comment: @J-16 SDiz The whoami is irrelevant to the question.  Substitute any command you wish to invoke remotely in its place.

Comment: Er...you might be better using a line oriented protocol (or at least a line oriented client). Sky high latency on a character-by-character protocol would be *much* more maddening than on a line or buffer oriented mechanism. Unfortunately, I can't think of one off the top of my head.

Comment: Can I ask what kind of a machine you were trying to SSH into? The latency sounds like a space probe of some kind :-) I am actually dealing with a similar issue - I'm trying to connect to a virtual machine (in order to stop some processes gracefully) that is so busy that the connection attempts keep timing out while exchanging keys. Were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: We are using inetd when there is huge latency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever tried using screen?  When I have a bad connection that keeps disconnecting me I make sure I use it so I don't lose my terminal session.

http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/

Comment: 'Screen' seems to be a GUI.  How do you pass a command to 'screen' to be evaluated from a script or C++ application without any GUI?

Comment: screen is an alternate terminal that you can reconnect to.  you can call scripts like any other terminal